browser.launchChromium throwing error after upgrading to Node20 for playwright-aws-lambda - error while loading shared libraries: libnspr4.so:
After upgrading lambda to Node 20 with playwright-aws-lambda browser.launchChromium throws below error:
/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnspr4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: browserType.launch: Target page, context or browser has been closed\nBrowser logs:\n\n<launching> /tmp/chromium --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate,HttpsUpgrades --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --disable-search-engine-choice-screen --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-domain-reliability --disable-extensions --disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-notifications --disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards --disable-popup-blocking --disable-print-preview --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-setuid-sandbox --disable-speech-api --disable-sync --disk-cache-size=33554432 --hide-scrollbars --ignore-gpu-blacklist --metrics-recording-only --mute-audio --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --no-pings --no-sandbox --no-zygote --password-store=basic --use-gl=swiftshader --use-mock-keychain --single-process --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-XXXXXX5R4V5P --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window\n<launched> pid=22\n[pid=22][err] /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnspr4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n[pid=22] <process did exit: exitCode=127, signal=null>\n[pid=22] starting temporary directories cleanup\nCall log:\n  - <launching> /tmp/chromium --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate,HttpsUpgrades --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --disable-search-engine-choice-screen --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-domain-reliability --disable-extensions --disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-notifications --disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards --disable-popup-blocking --disable-print-preview --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-setuid-sandbox --disable-speech-api --disable-sync --disk-cache-size=33554432 --hide-scrollbars --ignore-gpu-blacklist --metrics-recording-only --mute-audio --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --no-pings --no-sandbox --no-zygote --password-store=basic --use-gl=swiftshader --use-mock-keychain --single-process --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-XXXXXX5R4V5P --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window\n  - **<launched> pid=22\n  - [pid=22][err] /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnspr4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n**  - [pid=22] <process did exit: exitCode=127, signal=null>\n  - [pid=22] starting temporary directories cleanup\n"

import * as playwright from 'playwright-aws-lambda';
await playwright.launchChromium();
